# Parsing DateTime in a Model

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an employee model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
         ...
    public DateTime TerminationDate{ get; set; }
}
```

The model is populated automatically (by `HttpResponseMessage`'s `Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>()`)

The default value for TerminationDate (when the employee is still with the company) is `0000-00-00`, which can't be converted to a DateTime object, presumably because there is not 0th day or month. I get the error:

`Could not convert string to DateTime: 0000-00-00. Path 'terminationDate', line 1, position 533.`

The default date value can't be changed - I'm getting that from a 3rd party service.

The only workaround that I can think of is to set the TerminationDate to be a string, but then everything that gets the TerminationDate will have to parse it into a DateTime object.

Is there anything more elegant that I could do?

Comment: Not necessarily more elegant, but `DateTime?` is an option to have an "not set" value.

Comment: What I would do is create an entity class that represents the row of data and the data types of each field that is being retrieved. So if it's being stored as a string in the database, let the entity also have a string data type for that field. Using that object that represents a row, create an instance of the Employee object and parse or convert the values accordingly.

Comment: @JamesShaw I think that's the best solution, yes

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making the termination date to be nullable.

```
public DateTime? TerminationDate{ get; set; }
```

Since current employees don't have a `TerminationDate`, it would be reasonable to leave it as `null`.

Comment: @Default It makes sense since there's no termination date for that current  employee so why not leave it as null..

Comment: Good explanation and reasoning! How about [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29653398/edit) that in?

Comment: I just did, but I've had bad luck with editing so far.